Building a Java Library with Spring Boot - feasible?
I'm working on building a Java library using Spring Boot. This library is structured as a web application with REST endpoints, all of which function as expected. To enable its use in applications written in any JVM language, I created a factory class to manage the dependencies of the service classes as follows:
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

public class ServiceFactory {
    private static final FooMapper fooMapper = Mappers.getMapper(FooMapper.class);
    private static final BarMapper barMapper = Mappers.getMapper(BarMapper.class);

    public static FooService createFooService() {
        return new FooService(fooMapper, barMapper);
    }
}

A test confirms that the factory class successfully creates an instance of the service. However, when I call a method from the service class, a runtime exception occurs due to a malfunction in a custom annotation if the test class doesn't have the annotation @SpringBootTest. This has led me to question whether building a library with Spring Boot is feasible and if there might be other issues down the line.
Do you have any advice on this approach?

One of Spring's core features is its own dependency-injection system.  For a library, I'd normally expect the application that includes the library would take care of instantiating objects for you, or your object could be created as an ordinary Spring bean.  I'd avoid these static objects.

Building a Java Library with Spring Boot - feasible? Yes. You have a nice idea. See this way is more decent approach https://blog.ttulka.com/spring-boot-custom-components/ . You will create your own Spring Boot starter, your own auto configuration, your own public/private artifact.
